# How to get Django to redirect to the requested page with the LoginRequiredMixin after logging in?

Tags: django

Background:

I have an inventory application that scrapes through our VM and storage environments to index things for my team to have some quick references without having to log into vCenter/Storage systems directly to get info.

Since it's dealing with some potentially sensitive info, I put authentication on it by way of using the `LoginRequiredMixin` in my Views classes.  The authentication part has been in for a while and it works without issues.  The part where I get stuck on is I implemented the `next` parameter in the login form, and it shows up in the URL when it prompts to login.  I have a different view class for each kind of thing I'm tracking.

Goal:

When someone clicks on a link that requires authentication (basically every page except the main page), it redirects them to the page they want after requiring them to login.

I've seen a few other questions, but the recommendations mentioned haven't worked in my case for whatever reason.  I've tried various implements of the `redirect_field_name` but it still ends up trying to redirect to /accounts/profile if I don't have it overridden in the settings page.  I don't have the `login_url` field set, but the login page redirect works as expected.

----Code Snippets----

LoginView - Using Django's LoginView and authentication form as a base, and just piecing them together to keep my search capability at the top of the page.

```
class LoginView(SearchMixin, auth_views.LoginView):
    template_name = 'VMwareInventory/Registration/login.html'
    form = AuthenticationForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data()
        context['login_form'] = self.form
        return context
```

Example view that requires logging in. The url ends up correctly: /accounts/login?next=/Clusters/

```
class StorageView(SearchMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = StorageSystem
    template_name = 'VMwareInventory/Storage_templates/cluster_list_page.html'
    context_object_name = 'cluster_list'
    queryset = StorageSystem.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(StorageView, self).get_context_data()
        clusters = StorageSystem.objects.all()

        context['clusters'] = clusters

        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            sorting_method = self.request.GET.get('sorting_method')
            ascending = self.request.GET.get('ascending')
            data = []
            query = StorageSystem.objects.all()
            results = None
            if ascending == "true":
                results = query.order_by(sorting_method)
            elif ascending != "true":
                results = query.order_by(sorting_method).reverse()
            else:
                query = None
                data = serialize('json', None)

            if query is not None:
                for obj in results:
                    url_link = '<a href="' + obj.url + '">' + obj.name + '</a>'
                    json_data = {"name": url_link, "node_count": obj.node_count}
                    data.append(json_data)

            return JsonResponse(data=data, safe=False)
        else:
            return render(self.request, self.template_name, context=self.get_context_data())
```

Login.html page:

```
<div class="login" style="vertical-align: middle; height: 100%; margin-top: 13%">
        <table class="login" style="border: none; margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {% if form.errors %}
                        <p>Your username and/or password is incorrect.  Please try again</p>
                    {% endif %}

                    {% if next %}
                        <p>You need to login first before you can do that</p>
                    {% else %}
                        <p>To see this page, please login with Username and Password</p>
                    {% endif %}

                    <form method="post" action="{% url 'VMwareInventory:login' %}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ login_form.username.label_tag }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ login_form.username }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ login_form.password.label_tag }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ login_form.password }}</td>
                                </tr>
                        </table>
                        <div style="padding-top: 5px; text-align: center">
                            <input type="submit" value="login"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}"/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

urls:

```
path('accounts/login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('accounts/logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('accounts/password_change/', views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
    path('accounts/password_change/done/', views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='password_change_done')

path('Clusters/', views.StorageView.as_view(), name='storList'), # cluster url for view listed above.
```

Comment: This kind of goal can be achieved by writing your custom login view. And add support to the `next` parameter.

Comment: @Rvector I'm effectively doing that.  I have a custom login view that I'm using.  I've extended Django's `loginview` to keep the look consistent with the rest of my site.  In this case, is there a particular method I could override instead of having to build everything from scratch?  Because that seems contrary to what Django is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Try to override the `get` method of the `LoginView`, then redirect the user to the next page if `next` is present to the `kwargs` or `args`: by doing : `next_page = self.kwargs.get('next', None) if next_page: redirect(next_page)`

Comment: I kinda stumbled onto something similar.  Within the `LoginView` I overrided the `get_success_url` function from the `LoginView`.  I'm able to reliably pull the next value from the `request.GET.get('next')` however, the next value isn't getting embedded into the POST data for some reason.  So the `get_success_url` function is defaulting back to the `settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` variable (which I have set to the main page).

So, I think the root issue here is that the next value isn't getting sent along with the POST data.  Is there a way I can somehow put it into the POST request itself?

Comment: Yes if you render the Django form manually in the template. You can add an `<input type=hidden` like this in the login.html file `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />`

Comment: I had that in my html, but it wasn't picking it up for some reason with next.  I had to rename it to a different name (I chose redirect).  Then I captured it from the `next` info from GET, and populated it into the variable.  It worked like a charm after that.  

After that, it was just a matter of putting in a check to make sure it wouldn't try to redirect if someone clicked the login page manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after doing a bit of digging into some of Django code and seeing how the process works, I discovered that the `next` value wasn't getting pushed into the POST data.  So I ended up having to capture the `next` value from `request.GET.get('next')` and I pushed it to a `redirect` variable in the html (I changed that from the `next` variable that I had initially).

All in all, there were only a few changes that I made in the code to get this working.  I didn't have to re-create the entire view (which was helpful).

Hopefully this will help some others with this same issue get this up and running without having to completely rewrite a View, or override a bunch of methods.

Edit: I had to add a check to make sure that if there was no next value, then it wouldn't populate the redirect field.

LoginView:

```
class LoginView(SearchMixin, auth_views.LoginView):
    template_name = 'VMwareInventory/Registration/login.html'
    redirect_field_name = "redirect"  # added
    redirect_authenticated_user = True  # added
    form = AuthenticationForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data()
        context['login_form'] = self.form
        if self.request.GET.get('next'):
            context['redirect'] = self.request.GET.get('next')  # added

        return context
```

login.html:

```
<div class="login" style="vertical-align: middle; height: 100%; margin-top: 13%">
        <table class="login" style="border: none; margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {% if form.errors %}
                        <p>Your username and/or password is incorrect.  Please try again</p>
                    {% endif %}

                    {% if next %}
                        <p>You need to login first before you can do that</p>
                    {% else %}
                        <p>To see this page, please login with Username and Password</p>
                    {% endif %}

                    <form method="post" action="{% url 'VMwareInventory:login' %}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ login_form.username.label_tag }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ login_form.username }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ login_form.password.label_tag }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ login_form.password }}</td>
                                </tr>
                        </table>
                        <div style="padding-top: 5px; text-align: center">
                            <input type="submit" value="login"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ redirect }}"/>  # changed from before
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```